# Should we request a banner to communicate our policy regarding generative AI in posts?

Tags: discussion, how-to-answer, low-quality-posts

[Staff recently completed a test of a banner to inform users of a site's policy regarding the use of generative AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/572), finding that it doesn't significantly impact answer rates but that it does reduce the number of moderator flags for AI-generated content. As a result of the test, this feature is now available for all sites in the network as an optional feature.

[The network-wide policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384648/572) is that content created with generative AI must be cited as such. [Project Management's current stance](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/918/30) aligns with the network-wide policy and requires citation of any generative AI content.

This brings us to two questions:

1. Is our current policy to allow appropriately cited content produced with Generative AI still the desired wish of the community?
2. Do we want a banner informing users of our policy?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. In general, currently AI generated content is still low quality: too verbose, marketing- and sales- oriented, uncritical, not domain specific, prone to errors.
2. Yes

Answer (score 0):

### I'm Opposed to the Banner

We don't need the banner, and I personally don't want it. I could cite a lot of other reasons, but it all boils down to two key points:

1. It doesn't change the way we evaluate post quality in any meaningful way.
2. We don't need another UI widget cluttering up the site for a non-issue.

I don't want the visual cruft, nor do I have any intention of debating provenance with users. Many of the answers on this site are essentially informed opinions, and we've deliberately crafted the site that way because project management is not a hard science. Many shorter answers (my answers tend to be exceptions because of length and structure) don't even really need to cite anything, so there's not much point in having a big banner about about something that's largely irrelevant to the content or community-driven quality of this site.

If and when the site starts getting flooded with obvious (?!) AI-generated spam I might reconsider my view. At the moment, though, I am strongly against adding such a banner without a much more substantial benefit to the community or the site moderators.